# Action Form HTML

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web, formulário

Galera, recentemente me apareceu uma dúvida quando analisei alguns formulários em sites na web. Vou ser bem direto.

Porque alguns Forms HTML em algumas aplicações web utilizam em sua action um código javascript,

Por exemplo:

```
action="javascript:sendForm('parametros');"
```

Ao em vez de o caminho real que seria enviado:

```
action="/empresa/funcionarios/novo"
```

Qual a vantagem de utilizar esses actions? A única coisa que imaginei a qual me traria benefícios seria se um usuário desativasse o javascript então nenhuma comunicação seria estabelecida,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo [esta](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action) definição do atributo `action` :

tradução livre :

> Este atributo especifica um agente de processamento de formulários. O comportamento do agente do usuário para um valor diferente de um URI HTTP é indefinido.

No meu entendimento esse procesamento se dá através de uma linguagem server-side, mesmo que for usar o javascript para isso (talvez com node.js), existe o evento `onsubmit`.

É difícil responder : "Porque alguns Forms HTML em algumas aplicações web utilizam em sua action um código javascript ?"

Se for no `action`, vai saber... Não me parece adequado invocar funções javascript nos atributos `html` padrão, para isso o javascript tem toda a gama de eventos `on*`.

Em resumo só vejo desvantegens.